# How to maintain consistency for gremlin update operation in Azure Cosmos DB(Atomicity)?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a situation regarding how to maintain atomicity of transactions when making updates using the Azure CosmosDB Gremlin API.

**Scenario:** we are maintaining two graphs. The operation is to update one graph -> then update the other one -> then return a response if *both* operations are successful.

If one graph update is successful and another one fails, then it's difficult to handle consistency.

How do I handle the scenario when either of the update fails?

Answer (score 0):

As we could see that Transactions are not yet supported Gremlin API yet.

> Transactions aren't supported because of distributed nature of the
> system. Configure appropriate consistency model on Gremlin account to
> "read your own writes" and use optimistic concurrency to resolve
> conflicting writes."

Azure Cosmos DB supports Apache TinkerPop graph traversal language, Gremlin: A[zure Cosmos DB Gremlin graph support.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/gremlin-support)

Here, is the **similar issue:** How to handle transactions in Graph inserts | [Link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/74368517-ab9c-4540-ab68-af2428549272/how-to-handle-transactions-in-graph-inserts?forum=azurecosmosdb)